# Calculate difference between list of numbers from a file

Tags: bash, file

I've a file with a list of numbers as below

```
37298.1
37304.1
37310.3
37316.5
37322.5
37328.7
```

I need to calculate the difference between each number in the list with respect to the previous one, as showed below:

```
6.0
6.2
6.2
6.0
6.2
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'p{print $0-p}{p=$0}' file
```